# How to solve an 8bit shift register question?

Tags: arm, hardware, cpu-registers, shift-register

Assume an 8 bit shift register is loaded with the bit pattern `10110101` and that each clock pulse shifts this right one bit. What is the pattern on the shift register outputs after 2 clock pulses?

Assume that the register  is a barrel shifter.

```
A.11011010
B.01101011
C.01011010
D.10101101
```

How are the answers above possible?

```
Logical Shift Right - 2pulse
10110101
01011010 - first pulse
00101101 - second pulse
Rotate Logic Right
10110101
11011010
01101101
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a bad question, but the most plausible answer is D. The bottom 6 bits at least are correct. Also D would be 100% correct iff there is a carry bit, and the barrel shifter is doing a Rotate Right with Carry instruction ([RRX in ARM notation](http://www-mdp.eng.cam.ac.uk/web/library/enginfo/mdp_micro/lecture4/lecture4-3-4.html)). So they may have omitted vital information from the question, or it could just be a typo, but it would seem the least bad answer is D.

(Alternatively it could be any of the other answers, particularly B, with one or more typos.)

Comment: Can you please elaborate the RRC? To me it seems like in stead of assuming C as carry i have to assume 0.

Comment: It's RRX in ARM (RRC or RCR in various other ISAs) - see latest edit above. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10395112/253056)