# ASM disassembly RCR function call

Tags: assembly, x86-64, reverse-engineering, disassembly, ida

I disassembled some code and i get this function call , i guess from a `rcr` instruction , what is it really doing ?

`__RCR__(v8, v9)`

Comment: Which CPU architecture, and which disassembler?

Comment: Intel x64 with Ida Pro ( Hex Rays )

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10395071/what-is-the-difference-between-rcr-and-ror

Comment: Presumably `v8` is the input register and `v9` is `cl` (the rotate count).  It's decompiling, not just disassembling, right?  Because those aren't register names. I assume they're invented variable names.

Comment: `__RCR__` is a macro. Look in your IDA installation for `\plugins\defs.h` This file contains all of the macros used by the Hex-Rays decompiler.

Answer (score -1):

http://www.c-jump.com/CIS77/ASM/Assembly/A77_0420_rotate_with_carry.htm

RCR doing a rotate to the right and put on the left bit the value from Carry flag, The overridden bit will be in the Carry flag

AL = 01010100
CF = 1
ROR AL, 1;AL will be 10101010 and CF 0

Comment: Yes, we know what the asm instruction does.  But what semantics does the C function `__RCR__(int, int)` have?  Apparently from IDA decompiling machine code back to C source.