# Can someone explain me the output values for the below assembly code

Tags: assembly, x86

Can someone explain to me the output values for the below assembly code. Like how can I arrive at the solution?

```
Arr Byte 5D, 2E, 97, 4B, A5 , 7E , 84 , 9A , 61 , 8B 

     mov ecx, 5
     mov esi, offset Arr 

LI:  rcr array[esi], 1 
     Addi esi,esi, 2 
     Loop LI
```

Comment: @AlexGuteniev Yeah! now I've formatted it properly

Comment: `Addi esi, esi, 2` does not look like an x86 command. I assume `add esi, 2` or maybe `lea esi, [esi+2]`. Otherwise it looks like rotating some bytes in array though carry flag.

Comment: @AlexGuteniev This could be y86, a strange x86 variant.

Comment: @fuz, I've read about y86, it is simplified ISA that doesn't have complex x86 stuff like `rcr` or `loop`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's replace `Addi esi,esi, 2` with `lea esi, [esi+2]` because:

- There's no `Addi` in x86
- The intention seem to be to increment `esi` by 2
- `add` command affects `CF`, and `rcr` presumably expects `CF` from the previous iteration

No idea if there's some assembler to accept `Addi`.

---

The whole loop then runs in even-indexed elements of `Arr` (assume indexing is zero-based)

RCR rotates bits right through `CF` (Carry Flag). that is out of eight bits of each element each shifted towards less significance, the least significant bit is put into `CF` and the most significant bit is extracted from `CF`. See also:

- [What's the purpose of the rotate instructions (ROL, RCL on x86)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4976636/whats-the-purpose-of-the-rotate-instructions-rol-rcl-on-x86)
- [What is the difference between RCR and ROR?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10395071/what-is-the-difference-between-rcr-and-ror)

Knowing that, you can compute the new values of `Arr` element, except the 0th element: you don't know the initial value of `CF`.